# Is there some native support for taking aria-roledescription into account when selecting an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-selectors, react-testing-library, wai-aria

I have a page where there are two elements with `role="button"` and the same accessible name "Group Name". One of the elements also specifies `aria-roledescription="resize button"`. So a screenreader will announce the one element as "Group Name, button" and the other one as "Group Name, resize button".

After doing a bunch of [reading about `aria-roledescription`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-roledescription), I understand this is a valid use of that attribute (i.e. element still has a valid role and `aria-roledescription` is only used to make it more specific).

In my test when I want to select the element without the role description and I do `screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Group Name" })` I get the error that there are more than one element that match that query.

I can do `getAllByRole` and then just filter the elements. However, I was wondering if there is a more built in way in React Testing Library to select based on really what the screen reader would announce that takes role description into account.

e.g.

```
<button id="1" aria-roledescription="resize button">Group Name</button>
<div id="2" role="button">Group Name</div>

// returns item 2 (without role description)
screen.getByAnnouncedRole("button", { Name: "Group Name" })
// returns item 1 (with the role description "resize button")
screen.getByAnnouncedRole("resize button", { Name: "Group Name" })
```